# How can I LEFT JOIN a comma separated list?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to get a comma separated list from the mysql table but match the usernames of another table:

tasks:

```
--------------
id      people_id 
--------------
1       1,2     
2       3,4
```

members:

```
--------------
id      username 
--------------
1       James     
2       Alan
3       Frank
4       John
```

Here is what I tried:

```
   $result =  $db->query('
       SELECT *,
       group_concat(members.username)
       FROM tasks 
       LEFT JOIN members 
       ON find_in_set(members.id, tasks.people_id)
       ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The result I get I get is:

```
James
```

But I expect:

```
James, Alan
Frank, John
```

Comment: Fix your data model first - _normalize_ this properly! Apart from the current problem, you are likely to run into more issues based on this poor design choice of storing values comma separated in a single column later on.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, did like you sad and updated my question

Comment: @chris85 Alright, updated my question

Comment: Okay, the issue is still as @CBroe has said though. You need 1 row per value.

Comment: There are a few tiny rare occasions where storing a pre-defined comma list for an IN query would work... but the above example would not be one when you wish to JOIN tables by a single query. Not having the db structure different is whats giving you this blocker, and the solution (if the data must persist this way), is going to be messy.

Answer (score 2):

Hi please use the following query, you can use **find_in_set** for comma seperated values to check it.

```
select t.id, group_concat(m.username)
from tasks t
join members m on find_in_set(m.id, t.peopleid)
group by t.id
```

Comment: My result is now `James` `Frank` but not  `James, Alan` `Frank, John`

Comment: @Jarla Can you please send the dump of your database table. So that I will be able to test and give you the proper query